# A uniform bound on $u_n$ in $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have a sequence $u_n$ satisfying

$$\lVert u_n \rVert_{L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))} \leq C$$
for all $n$.

Can I get a weak-* convergent sequence?

I don't know if $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ is the dual $L^1(0,T;L^1(\Omega))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Banach space $B$, the space $L^1(0,T;B)$  is naturally identified with $L^\infty(0,T;B^*)$ **if and only if** $B^*$ has the [Radon-Nikodym property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_property). The space $L^\infty(\Omega)$ does not have the RNP.

In general, the dual of $L^1(0,T;B)$ is the larger space $\Lambda^\infty(0,T;B^*)$ which consists of *weak*-measurable* functions $f$ with $\|f\|_{B^*}\in L^\infty$. The weak* measurability means that for every $v\in B$, the scalar function $\langle v,f\rangle$ is measurable.

So, you can get a weak* convergent net to an element of $\Lambda^\infty(0,T;B^*)$. And a sequence if $L^1(0,T;B)$ is separable, which it is in your case.

As a freely available source, I recommend the lecture notes [Martingales in Banach Spaces](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~pisier/ihp-pisier.pdf) by Pisier.